# Displaying category url with only name laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to display category url with name and not id , eg. `http://567.0.0.1:23/category/Women`. In categories table, there is `Id`, and `name` columns also in products table there is `category_id` column.  So far the url displays empty category, how can I  make it display url with name?

Route

```
 Route::get('/category/{name}', 'HomeController@showCates');
```

Href

```
 `<a href="http://567.0.0.1:23/category/Women"></a>`
```

Controller

```
    public function showCates($id)
    {
    $category_products=product::where('category_id',$id)->get();
    $id_ =$id;
    return     view('front.category_list_pro',compact('category_products', 'id_'));
    }
```

Comment: I did not understand what is your problem

Comment: You should have a relationship between Category and Product, in case can you show it.

Comment: Currently the url is like this `href="http://567.0.0.1:23/category/21` which is women category , I want the url to be `href="http://567.0.0.1:23/category/Women` so instead of id I want it to be replaced with category name @GiacomoM

Comment: you create the url, so I still do not understand what your problem is

Comment: I was trying to make it work so I replaced the id with name `women` -> `href="http://567.0.0.1:23/category/Women` this url shows empty category with no products  but If I change it like this `href="http://567.0.0.1:23/category/21` it shows all products in category women. @GiacomoM

Comment: I guess there is a relationship between Product and Category models. It must be. Please edit your question to add the relationship

Answer (score 2):

If you want the URL to show category name instead of ID you can create a new **unique** column for categories table named `slug`.

After creating a category you could automatically assign it a slug field via Laravel mutators:

```
// inside Category model
public function setNameAttribute($name)
{
    $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($name);
    $this->attributes['name'] = $name;
}
```

then you can access the route like:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'CategoryController@show',
    'as' => 'category.show'
]);
```

in blade templates you can create URL like:

```
{{ url('/category', ['slug' => $category->slug]) }}
```

which would result in e.g. `http://567.0.0.1:23/category/women`

inside controller:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    return view('category.show', compact('category'));
}
```